# MySQL stored procedure Error - Create table from param names

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying the following but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'f' in 'where clause'
```

I'm seriously confused because `f` is a parameter of `createtableTest`...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createtableTest
(
tname2 varchar(20),
f varchar(20)
)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname2;
CREATE TABLE tname2 as SELECT * FROM data WHERE group_name like f;
END;
```

Comment: @JW 웃 , What exactly did you edit? Was it adding the `sql` tag? I'm pretty sure the specific question is MySQL specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `f` is contains the value, a dynamic sql is needed so we can concatenate it with the original query,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE createtableTest(IN tname2 varchar(20),IN f varchar(20))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname2;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE tname2 as SELECT * FROM data WHERE group_name like ''%',f,'%''');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

for example, the value of `f` is `hello`, the concatenated string will produce

```
CREATE TABLE tname2 as SELECT * FROM data WHERE group_name like '%hello%'
```

**UPDATE**

- [MySQL Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Aside from concatenation, you can also parameterized the value which is the best way, ex

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE createtableTest(IN tname2 varchar(20),IN f varchar(20))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname2;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE tname2 as SELECT * FROM data WHERE group_name like ?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    SET @val = CONCAT('%', f, '%');
    EXECUTE stmt USING @val;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```